# Loop higher order function without using forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays

How would I loop through the array without using forEach? A bit confused about higher order functions, and not sure about the syntax. thank you

As an example, 3 alerts from:

`myFunc([1,2,3])`

Comment: *Why*?  Is this an academic exercise?  Are you trying to write a bespoke version of `forEach`?  (Not hard, BTW, but rarely useful.)  If instead someone told you to skip `forEach` in favor of more semantic functions, then things like `map`, `find`, `filter`, `some`, `every`, and `reduce` are the usual ones to choose.  But all of them are about transformations, and not side effects.  If you just want the side effect of `alert`, then `forEach` or a `for`-loop will do fine.

Comment: Welcome!
Either `array.forEach(element=>alert(element))` which you don't want,
`array.reduce((accumulator, currentValue)=>alert(currentValue),0)`, or
`for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++) alert(array[i])`...
`while(array.length) alert(array.shift())` - if not in function, it will empty the array...

Comment: @iAmOren: I would argue that this is an abuse of `reduce`.  The others make sense.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, I agree.  They are all abuse in one way or another - op should just use `forEach`...

Comment: Yes this is simply to practice the loops. Surely I will start using forEach. Thanks everyone. Cheers @iAmOren

Comment: @EST201, do look at Scott's and my suggestions - Look at [`Array` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Comment: @ScottSauyet We _could_ also consider a recursive `loop` function as well. Not that we _should_ but it's an alternative especially if OP is learning high order functions. I would agree that this wouldn't be the best example but `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @customcommander: certainly.  But recursion is classically tied to FP, where side-effects are usually considered an anathema.  As with many options: Could we? *Yes*.  Should we?  *Probably not*.  But for coding practice, almost anything goes.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a regular `for` loop

```js
myFunc([1,2,3], alert)

function myFunc(arr, func) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    func(arr[i]);
}
```